# Is there any public implementation / publication with Hintons capsules idea?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

In Hintons talk "[What's wrong about convolutional nets](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929075327/http://d1baxxa0joomi3.cloudfront.net/69bf620e48d60761118dc4328f5d6e9c/basic.mp4)" (Late 2016 or early 2015, I guess) he talks about capsules to make a modular CNN.

Is there any publicly available implementation or papers about this idea?

Answer (score 1):

Following the publication of Dynamic Routing of Capsules (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829), there have been open source implementations of this idea released. See https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras and https://github.com/soskek/dynamic_routing_between_capsules for two such examples.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd add a selection of what's of some of the 'best' stuff out there to suit different learning styles :)

Literature
- [Original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.09829) by Sara Sabour, Nicholas Frosst, Geoffrey E Hinton

Blog post
- [Understanding Hinton’s Capsule Networks. Part I: Intuition](https://medium.com/ai%C2%B3-theory-practice-business/understanding-hintons-capsule-networks-part-i-intuition-b4b559d1159b) by Max Pechyonkin

Youtube video
- [Capsule Networks (CapsNets) – Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPN8d0E3900) by Aurélien Géron

Implementation
- [Keras implementation](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras) by Xifeng Guo

More reading
- [Github repository containing comprehensive list of CapsNet info](https://github.com/loretoparisi/CapsNet)